# dynamic tf broadcaster updates stale/intermittent in tf view_frames

Tags: ros-melodic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS,
Jetson nano,
Ros melodic

My robot platform is an inverted pendulum, and trying to implement a dynamic transform between the base_link (centered between wheels and fixed w/r/t gravity vector), and base_frame (co-located with base_link, but includes the pitch measurement).  The sensor that is providing the attitude measurement also produces a visual odometry measurement, so I have an odom_listener node that will send an updated base_link to base_frame transform, and a base_link to camera_odom_frame transform on every new measurement.

However, when I run "tf view_frames", I will only infrequently see the base_link to base_frame or camera_odom_frame nodes, and if I do, the measurements are typically many seconds old.  If I run "tf tf_echo base_link base_frame", I can usually see tf broadcast updates, but interestingly, they can show the same "At time" values for multiple broadcasts:

```
$ rosrun tf tf_echo base_link base_frame 

At time 1568583863.323
- Translation: [0.000, 0.000, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.002, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY (radian) [0.000, 0.003, 0.000]
            in RPY (degree) [0.000, 0.186, 0.000] 

At time 1568583863.323
- Translation: [0.000, 0.000, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.002, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY (radian) [0.000, 0.003, 0.000]
            in RPY (degree) [0.000, 0.186, 0.000]
```

Looking at the code in the odom_listener.cpp, I print updates regularly, and can see the code is getting called with a much higher frequency that I'm observing updates in view_frame or tf_echo.  Any thoughts why?

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h"

/**
 * http://wiki.ros.org/evarobot_odometry/Tutorials/indigo/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Subscriber%20for%20Odometry
 * https://answers.ros.org/question/11545/plotprint-rpy-from-quaternion/#17106
 */

/**
 * on VO message from T265, updates base_link to base_frame transform used
 * by GPS and laser.  Also transforms the VO data to the base_link frame
 */
void odomCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    // Inspect incoming message
    ROS_INFO("Seq: [%d]", msg->header.seq);
    //ROS_INFO("Position-> x: [%f], y: [%f], z: [%f]", msg->pose.pose.position.x,msg->pose.pose.position.y, msg->pose.pose.position.z);
    //ROS_INFO("Orientation-> x: [%f], y: [%f], z: [%f], w: [%f]", msg->pose.pose.orientation.x, msg->pose.pose.orientation.y, msg->pose.pose.orientation.z, msg->pose.pose.orientation.w);
    //ROS_INFO("Vel-> Linear: [%f], Angular: [%f]", msg->twist.twist.linear.x,msg->twist.twist.angular.z);

    // Construct tf::Quaterion
    tf::Quaternion quat(msg->pose.pose.orientation.x, 
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.y, 
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.z, 
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.w);

    // Get RPY from Quaternion
    double roll, pitch, yaw;
    tf::Matrix3x3(quat).getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
    
    // Display converted RPY
    ROS_INFO("published rpy angles: roll=%f pitch=%f yaw=%f", roll, pitch, yaw);
    
    //Update tf::Quaternion with pitch only
    tf::Quaternion qPitchOnly;
    qPitchOnly.setRPY(0.0, pitch, 0.0);

    //base_link to base_frame transformation
    tf::TransformBroadcaster broadcaster;
    ros::Time currentTime = ros::Time::now();

    double secs = currentTime.toSec();
    ROS_INFO("currentTime: [%f]", secs);

    broadcaster.sendTransform(
        tf::StampedTransform(
            tf::Transform(qPitchOnly, tf::Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
            currentTime,"base_link", "base_frame"
        )
    );

    // Transform T265 data to base_link frame and broadcast
    tf::Vector3 baseLink2T265 = tf::Vector3(0.122, 0.0, 0.187);
    tf::Vector3 result = tf::Matrix3x3(qPitchOnly) * baseLink2T265;

    broadcaster.sendTransform(
        tf::StampedTransform(
            tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), result),
            currentTime,"base_link", "camera_odom_frame"
        )
    );

    ROS_INFO("New location-> x: [%f], y: [%f], z: [%f]", result.x(), result.y(), result.z());

    //ROS_INFO("New Orientation-> x: [%f], y: [%f], z: [%f], w: [%f]", quat.x(), quat.y(), quat.z(), quat.w());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "odom_listener");

  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/camera/odom/sample", 1000, odomCallback);

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333071/dynamic-tf-broadcaster-updates-stale/intermittent-in-tf-view_frames/) by [Jimboner](https://answers.ros.org/users/45653/jimboner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your code shows this:

```
void odomCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    [..]

    tf::TransformBroadcaster broadcaster;

    [..]

    broadcaster.sendTransform(..);

    [..]
}
```

you're (re)creating the `tf::TransformBroadcaster` in every `odomCallback(..)`.

As broadcasters essentially wrap regular `ros::Publisher`s, the same requirements and constraints apply: *never* create `Publisher`s inside the body of callbacks.

Setting up a publication takes time. Setting up subcriptions takes time. There is almost no time between creating the `TransformBroadcaster` and sending transforms with it in your code. And even if the subscription is setup, the `Publisher` disappears almost immediately after the frames have been broadcast, which increases the chance that the data never actually reaches the subscriber(s).

Create the `TransformBroadcaster` in a scope that has a longer lifetime than your callback -- such as your `main(..)`, or use a class to wrap all of this -- and I expect things to start working properly.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jimboner](https://answers.ros.org/users/45653/jimboner/) on 2019-09-19**:
Gvdhoorn,

Thanks for the quick response, wrapping it into a class works great!

Jim